# TinyTds::Error: Server name not found in configuration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, tiny-tds

I am using Docker + Rails + Tiny TDS on Windows. 
This configuration worked great until I started dockerizing the environment. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Gemfile

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
```

DockerFile

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq freetds-bin    

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/

# Start the main process.

RUN dos2unix entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


EXPOSE 3000
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  server:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rake db:create && rake db:migrate &&  bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    links:
      - db
      - redis

    volumes:
        # - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
         - .:/usr/src/app
        #    - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "1433:1433"
      - "1434:1434"

    environment:

      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@db:5432/app?pool=25&encoding=unicode&schema_search_path=public
      # DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY: RANDOM_SECRET
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
```

When I test the connection

```rb
    client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    port: 1433,
    host: 'server_name', # works if you are not using docker
    # dataserver: 'server_name', #This did not work as well
    timeout: 10000
```

Error message:

> TinyTds::Error: Server name not found in configuration files from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/tiny_tds-1.0.4/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:43:in
>   `connect'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to replace `server_name` with its IP address. If this will work, you have some issues with name resolution (DNS resolver) inside the container.

Comment: I have tried the IP address, that did not help the situation.

Comment: @lyzard-kyng, after further testing in Rails console, the server name had to have the full suffix of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @lyzard-kyng comment on the question the IP address helped diagnose the issue.
The DNS suffix properties were managed by windows. I had to add them to the server_name.